# If statement always proving false when using the $_GET[] global variable set with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I started learning about AJAX very recently and this little problem seemed to have come out of no where. I wrote an html page that uses this code to create an AJAX connection and send a get request with an id.

```
        function loadXML() {
            var xmlhttp;
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }else{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "textTesting.php?id='first'", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

In my textTesting.php, just for the sake of testing, I compared incoming variable $_GET[id] with the string I expect to be true, first. But the comparison always seem to fail for some reason.

textTesting.php:

```
<?php
$output = "";
if(isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $output = $_GET["id"];
    if($output == 'first'){
        $output .= " confirmed";
    }
}
echo $output;
?>
```

Is there a concept of PHP or AJAX that I am missing? When writing this if statement I was expecting 'first confirmed' to become the output.

Please ask any further question if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you are passing is `'first'` but you are comparing it against `first` so it doesn't match.

In your query string the quotes are data. In your PHP, the quotes are string delimiters.

Either add quotes to the data in the PHP or remove them from the query string.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see what you are saying.